# How to programmatically move limbs of 3d model in unity according to gyroscope orientation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino, skeletal-mesh

I have a number of gyroscopes(in real life) attached to my body on my arms, legs, head and spine. Each gyroscope has a unique id, which I map to a body part on the 3d model.

The gyroscope data for each sensor is a quaternion.

I basically just want to animate my 3d model based on this data.

So if I rotate my head to the right, the 3d model should rotate its head similarly. If I stand on one leg, the 3d model should do the same.

When using 2d physics engines like Box2d, this is as simple as applying a transform. What is the equivalent way to do this in Unity ?

EDIT: In Godot its really simple.

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/tutorials/3d/working_with_3d_skeletons.html

```
extends Spatial
var skel
var id

func _ready():
    skel = get_node("skel")
    id = skel.find_bone("upperarm")
    print("bone id:", id)
    var parent = skel.get_bone_parent(id)
    print("bone parent id:", id)
    var t = skel.get_bone_pose(id)
    print("bone transform: ", t)
    set_process(true)

func _process(delta):
    var t = skel.get_bone_pose(id)
    t = t.rotated(Vector3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), 0.1 * delta)
    skel.set_bone_pose(id, t)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you would need to do from the broad description in the question, but a good place to start could be setting `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(triplet.x, triplet.y, triplet.z);` on the `GameObject` representing the object the gyroscope is on.

Comment: @Ruzhim - Since all bones are connected, does that mean I need to create a game object for each bone in a skeleton ? This seems like the kind of thing there would already be a solution for. Take a look at this link: https://hackaday.com/2016/01/23/amazing-imu-based-motion-capture-suit-turns-you-into-a-cartoon/ The code he uses in the python script to access the blender api is really simple. I'm trying to figure out the equivalent in Unity.

Comment: @Ruzihm If you see the Godot example I've posted, it may be clearer what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: looking at the arduino code, it collects **quaternions**, *not* the euler angles or axis/angle state of each  gyroscope. I'm editing the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, you can apply a quaternion rotation to a transform (overwriting its previous rotation) like this:

```
float quatX,quatY,quatZ,quatW;

Quaternion quat = new Quaternion(quatX,quatY,quatZ,quatW);
transform.rotation = quat;
```

If the problem then is that your arduino outputs **right-handed** quaternions, and that you need to convert them to the **left-handed** quaternions that unity uses, then [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/157954/121653) by stackexchange user [DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory) by may help you make the conversion in Unity:

> A quaternion can be thought of as an angle-axis representation:
>
> ```
> quaternion.xyz = sin(angle/2) * axis.xyz
> quaternion.w = cos(angle/2)
> ```
>
> So, converting them between two coordinate systems can be broken down
>   into two steps:
>
> 1. Map the axis into the new coordinate system.
> 2. If changing between left & right hand coordinates (eg. if there's an odd number of axis negations or axis exchanges between the two),
>      negate the angle.
>
>    Since `cos(-angle) = cos(angle)` and `sin(-angle) = -sin(angle)`
>      this is the same as flipping the axis of rotation, negating the x, y,
>      and z parts.
>
> Taking your specific example:
>
> ```
>          sensor   unity
> forward    x        z
> up         z        y
> right     -y        x
> ```
>
> We can combine these steps into:
>
> ```
> Quaternion ConvertToUnity(Quaternion input) {
>     return new Quaternion(
>          input.y,   // -(  right = -left  )
>         -input.z,   // -(     up =  up     )
>         -input.x,   // -(forward =  forward)
>          input.w
>     );
> }
> ```